# Python Salsa20 implementation

Tags: python, encryption, stream, cryptography

I am looking for Salsa20 or ChaCha20 stream cipher integration in Python. One [listed here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/salsa20/0.3.0) seems to reset key position every time you call `Salsa2_xor` which defeats the purpose of Salsa being stream cipher. Code will be running in Python 2.x on Linux.

If you know any well tested implementations or libraries please list them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The author of ChaCha20, Daniel J. Bernstein, has an implementation here https://github.com/Daeinar/salsa20

That's about as authoritative as it gets :)

Comment: This implementation doesn't look like it was created by DJB. This may be a misinterpretation of the remark "Created by Daniel J. Bernstein" in the readme, which is referring to the fact that DJB designed Salsa20.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's [Python NaCl](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl) bindings which I should be able to use.